# Trouble with my scheme function that tries to create production values with a given grammar

Tags: scheme, racket

So I am trying to create a function where given the following input `'((a (xz) (c)) (b (wy) (d)))`
I am supposed to do something like this`'((a (xz)) (a (c)) (b (wy)) (b (d)))`

I tried to write this

```
(define productionValues
  (lambda (input)
    (let ((lhs (map (lambda (x) (car x)) input)))
      (let ((rhs (map (lambda (y) (cdr y)) input)))
        (map (lambda (l) (cons l (map (lambda (r) (car r)) rhs))) lhs)
        )
      )
  ))
```

This does not work and gets me `((a (xz) (c)) (b (xz) (c)))`
My logic behind this is I have a variable **lhs** that stores `(a b)` and **rhs** that stores `(((xz) (c)) ((wy) (d)))` and I would try to use another set of map functions to grab from the between the two variables, but I feel like I'm on somewhat the right track but just don't understand how i could get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish there - but this produced the desired output:

```
(define (productionValues input)
  ; flatten the sublists
  (apply append
         ; create the lists as per the sample
         (map (lambda (x) (list (list (first x) (second x))
                                (list (first x) (third  x))))
              input)))
```

For example:

```
(define input '((a (xz) (c)) (b (wy) (d))))
(productionValues input)
=> '((a (xz)) (a (c)) (b (wy)) (b (d)))
```

Comment: The overall goal of this project is to build an LL(1) parser and this is one of my functions that takes functions with the same non terminal and merge them onto one line.  
For example 
[a ::= (xz) | (c) ]    
 b ::= (wy) | (d) ]
is converted to this in scheme '((a (xz) (c)) (b (wy) (d))), and i have to take each left hand symbol and apply it to the appropriate rule. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @onbu ok, thanks for the context :) anyway, that doesn't change my answer, it's giving the correct output for your sample input. Unless you have a counter-example, I think we can mark is as correct now ;)

Comment: yea thanks, took me a while to apply your logic into what i wanted.